# On Button Click I generate a PDF file and then open it at server side with:

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.TransmitFile(path);
```

open in same tab i want to open different tab .

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a new page and open that page in a new window on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Set your link or form target to `_blank`. That will force it open the result in another window

```
<a href="urlOfThePage" targret="_blank" >Click me</a>
```

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownloadPdf" CssClass="downloadpdf" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("fld_Patient_Id") %>'
                                                                                                CommandName="download"><span style="margin-left: 10px">open pdf</span>
                                                                                            </asp:LinkButton> link button to open pdf ...I want to open pdf using code behind in c#.

Comment: If you set the link to an aspx page, it will come to your code behind. Link buttons don't allow you to get a target.

Comment: how can open pdf in new  tab click on link button :)

Comment: Why are you repeating the question? an aspx file can output a pdf. You seem to know that cause you have posted the code to do it in your question. Set the href to point to the aspx page that has that code.

Comment: I am creating the pdf in code behind the i want to open new window or tab ..?

Comment: What part of my earlier comments did you not understand? This question is already answered.

Comment: Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+filePath); 
Response.WriteFile(path);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();**bold**

Answer (score 0):

If you have to open the pdf in new tab, you would have to open the downloading page in new tab in following way by using `_blank` in [target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute

```
<a href="pdf.aspx" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownloadPdf" CssClass="downloadpdf" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("fld_Patient_Id") %>'
                                                                                                CommandName="download"><span style="margin-left: 10px">open pdf</span>
                                                                                            </asp:LinkButton> link button to open pdf ...I want to open pdf using code behind in c# . please give me another solution

Comment: The LinkButton control has the same appearance as a HyperLink control, but has the same functionality as a Button control. If you want to link to another Web page when the control is clicked, consider using the HyperLink control....

Comment: how can open pdf in new tab click on link button :)  in code behind

Comment: I got the answer **bold ** 'Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+filePath);' 
Response.WriteFile(path);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();